# Как сделать оплату кредитными картами в андроид приложении?

Tags: платежи

Как реализовать в андроид приложении оплату картами? Как это делается или пример, если можно. Не google pay и не paypal

Comment: Воспользуйтесь любым удобным мерчантом, либо подключитесь к агрегаторам QIWI / YANDEX.

Answer (score 0):

Тут вам в помощь [Яндекс Касса](https://kassa.yandex.ru) или [FreeCassa](https://www.free-kassa.ru). Про ФриКассу не уверен, но Яндекс касса будет требовать наличие юридического лица, иначе никак. Нет юр. лица - нет кассы, нет оплат

Еще есть Яндекс деньги, но не уверен, что вам это подойдет, там большие проблемы в сопоставлении конкретного пользователя и тех денег которые вам пришли. Т.е. вы получите уведомление об оплате, но от кого именно они пришли установить будет сложно

Короче говоря ищите шлюз связи с банком, в разделе API они вам все расскажут

Так-же следует ознакомиться со стандартом PCI DSS